# Javascript situations where it is GOOD to declare a global variable?

Tags: javascript, global-variables

When is it ***GOOD*** to declare a global variable in JavaScript?  Typical advice concerning global variables includes:

I sometimes encounter situations where it is critical that the value of a variable is available for the duration of the activity of the user.  For example, knowing the state of which page is open.  Another situation is when there is a long process with lots of smaller functions, but some value needs to be maintained throughout the process.  Rather than passing an argument from function to function to function, and hope it doesn't get to confusing, just create a global variable.

- In general, it's bad practice to declare global variables.
- Can cause problems with "Namespace Pollution".
- Duplicate variable declarations of the same name inside and outside of a function.
- Global variables are slower to look up than local variables.
- It's easy to forget that you declared the global variable, because it's out of site from the current code you are working on.
- Tracking and debugging a global variable is hard.
- Asynchronous use of the global variable could cause concurrency issues.

### Situations where it would be good to declare a global variable?

- A constant that has a lot of characters in it, that is used a lot.  Reduce the size of overall code.
- Saving the state of the current condition of something that must be monitored, and available at all times to more than one function.

It seems to me that the requirements would be:

- High usage and/or
- Required by at least two different functions that are outside the scope of each other.

### Examples:

### Object with many characters:

```
var dc = document;
var isTheMenuDisplayed = dc.getElementById('MainMenu').style.display;
```

### Monitor Current State:

What page is currently displayed:

```
/* The state of what page is currently display, must be available to
  the entire application at all times.
  Variable is declared outside of a function enclosure.
*/

var whichPageDisplayed = '';

function changePage(pageNameToOpen) {
  if (whichPageDisplayed === 'home') {
    close the home page;
    open the new page;
    //Make sure to record what the new current open page is
    whichPageDisplayed = pageNameToOpen;
};
```

I'm looking for reasons about when it's *GOOD* to use a global variable.

If global variables are considered always bad, then how do I deal with the above two situations without a global variable?

The "Asynchronous use of the global variable could cause concurrency issues" reason shouldn't be exclusive to global variables.  Asynchronous use of anything could cause concurrency issues, so I don't see how that is an argument against global variables.

The "It's easy to forget that you declared the global variable, because it's out of site from the current code you are working on" reason seems like a coding discipline issue.  If I saw that there was no `var = thisVar` statement anywhere to be found in that section of code, I'd think to myself, "Maybe I declared it as a global variable?".  Then I'd do a search to find it.

"Tracking and debugging a global variable is hard" I have a "Search All Files" option in my code editor.  It searches all the files, and shows me every line of code where the search found a match.  It's not that hard.  Depending on what browser and what developer tools I'm using, an error msg may show me the exact line of code where the error came from.

Comment: This doesn't really seem particularly JS specific; I wonder if it would fare better on Programmers.se

Comment: Like you said, high usage or something that you'll need available at all times. And helper functions like `var $ = function (id) {return document.getElementById(id);};`.

Comment: Declare a revealing module and expose whatever you need to your other modules. Or use the jQuery `data()` method to store it in the `$.cache`. It will be global, but not polluting the global namespace.

Comment: You could possibly get this reopened by phrasing it as a question more aligned as "how do I make these not require globals?"

Answer (score 2):

Reducing the overall code size isn't a valid reason. Minifiers will knock it down. Besides, if you have something like your example of `dc.getElementById('MainMenu').style.display`, you want a **method** to help you. Such as `getDisplayStyle('MainMenu')`. Doing that is just good practice, as it allows you to keep the logic in one spot.

Saving state isn't really a valid reason either. Keep your code in modules. For example, your code turned into something a bit "better":

```
PageState = {
    changePage: function (pageNameToOpen) {
        if(this._currentPage == 'home') {
        /*******/
        }
        this._currentPage = pageNameToOpen;
    },
    getCurrentPage: function () {
        return this._currentPage;
    }
};
PageState.changePage(pageNameToOpen);
```

The only times you should consider a global variable is if a library requires it, or if you need to setup configuration options on something before that "something" exists (and you are not using AMD type modules). For example, one of the popular WYSIWYG editors out there looks specifically for a global variable that defines some constants for setup.

Basically, for almost every possible usage of global variables, there is counter argument for wrapping it in a module of some sort.

Comment: Okay, so that code uses `this` to store data in a variable named `_currentPage`?  And the value in `this._currentPage` is maintained.  Is it maintainted because everything is wrapped in an array `PageState`?

Comment: The *Object* `PageState`, yes. You got it.

Comment: Is the _Object_ being stored globally?  Do you create the _Object_ outside of a function?  Or do you put the _Object_ inside of another function?  In this case, it's the `PageState` _Object_.

Comment: Depends. In this case there is no need to put this anywhere other than on the global scope (there really is nowhere else you *could* put it, besides wrapping it in your application's closure or namespace). If you were using AMD style modules, you could define 'PageState' as that object, then inject it into the places where it is needed. Or if you were using something like Angular, that also has injection capabilities.

Comment: I'm trying to compare putting a variable in the global scope versus putting an object in the global scope that in turn holds the variable that I would have put in the global scope.  Either way I'm putting something in the global scope.  Unless JavaScript somehow manages that 'PageState' object in the global scope differently than it manages a variable put into the global scope, it seems like both strategies end up at exactly the same place.

Comment: There is always going to be *something* in the global scope (i.e. `document` or `window` or `Math`). The point is that you don't want to just throw things into it. In the PageState example you have a conceptual segment of your coding space contained - this "thing" has the job of managing the state of the page. Anytime you need to do something related to that, you have one point of truth. If, for example, you needed to 'save' the state and determine if it is saved, you would not want to also have a global variable of "pageStateSaved" to check.

Comment: Yes, I agree with being able to easily track down the connections.